# Deep copy of a vector of structures from CPU to Device

Tags: c++, cuda, gpgpu

I have a vector of structures as follows:

```
    struct nuc{
    double Ax;
    double Ay;
    double Az;
    };

    struct Cont{
      int owner_ID;
      nuc A;
      double c[20];
      double e[20];

      int am;
      int size;
      double nrn;
    };

    struct L{
      int n1;
      int n2;
      int n3;
    };


    struct Atomic_Orbital{
      L  ag;
      Cont cont;
    };
vector<Atomic_Orbital> B;

    B.resize(100);
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
    .........
    }
```

and I want to do a deep copy from the CPU to the device of the STL vector of structures B. How can I do it properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::vector` stores its elements contiguously in memory—it's basically a normal array with fancy accessors and resizers added. And since all of the structures in question are trivially copyable (they contain POD types only and do not have custom copy/move constructors), `cudaMemcpy` can copy them just fine. So you'd do something like this:

```
Atomic_Orbital *devPtr;
size_t size = B.size() * sizeof(Atomic_Orbital);
cudaMalloc(&devPtr, size);
cudaMemcpy(devPtr, B.data(), size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

(Error checking, trivial casts etc. omitted)

To copy the data back from device to host, just use the opposite copying direction:

```
cudaMemcpy(B.data(), devPtr, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot  for answer (a typo: CudaMemcpyHostToDevice -> cudaMemcpyHostToDevice ), How can I bring back the data  to the CPU?